# In R Shiny, is there a way to get a reactive value when recovering an error with option 'shiny.error'?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, shiny-reactivity

I would like to make shiny application that can retrieve some reactive value (initialized with `reactiveVal`) so that, when an error occure, I can save the value of my "reactive value" just before the application breaks.

I tried a few things with the option "`shiny.error`" (`options(shiny.error = function(){...})`)" but I can get these value...

Here is a skeleton of a simple app :

```
library(shiny)
options(shiny.error = function() {
  previous_frames <- sys.frames()
  ## Some code that enables to get the value of the reactive value "rv" 
  ## when the error occured (and save in a file "recover.txt" for instance).

  ## I expected that I could retrieve the reactive value in "previous_frames",
  ## but it seems not to be the case...
})


ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    actionButton("increment", label = "Increment")
    , textOutput("value")
    , actionButton("do_error", "Create an error")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  rv <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$increment, {
    rv(rv() + 1)
  })
  output$value <- renderText({
    rv()
  })

  observeEvent(input$do_error, {
    stop("an error")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Do you have any idea how I can retrieve the value of a "reactive value" (i.e. initialized with `reactiveVal`, in this case the value of `rv()`)  when an error occure (preferably using option  `shiny.error`)?

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a simple solution: place the `options` call in the server function and call directly the value in an `observer`:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tagList(
    actionButton("increment", label = "Increment")
    , textOutput("value")
    , actionButton("do_error", "Create an error")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  options(shiny.error = function() {
   # I can retrieve the value :)
observe({
  print(paste0("value = ",rv()))
})
  })

  rv <- reactiveVal(0)
  observeEvent(input$increment, {
    rv(rv() + 1)
  })
  output$value <- renderText({
    rv()
  })

  observeEvent(input$do_error, {
    stop("an error")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)*
```